# display error message thrown by ms sql in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i've been looking for a solution for weeks now. yet still failed..i have stored procedure that was called using in ruby on rails..in that stored proc i have validations and thrown using raiserror.

ex. raiserror("StartDate must be less than EndDate")

in my ruby on rails controller

def save
 begin
  M.find_by_sql "EXEC spTestProc '3/15/2010', '3/1/2010'"
 rescue Exception => e
  render :js => alert(e.message);
end

but instead i get the error message **"StartDate must be less than EndDate"**, I got this error message "DBI::DatabaseError: 37000 (50000) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]StartDate must be less than EndDate..: Exec spTestProc '3/15/2010', '3/1/2010'"

I need to display the error message thrown by my stored proc, but i got some additional message that I dont like to display like "DBI::DatabaseError...etc." how can I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to remove the unwanted text.

```
e.message.gsub(/(^.*SQL Server\])|(: Exec spTestProc.*$)/i, '')
# this will return StartDate must be less than EndDate..
```

Comment: but is there no built in function in the Exception class where it would just get the actual errors? like in asp.net, it gets the actual error message. thanks

Comment: It is quite likely that ASP.net is doing this step for you.